# How to take list of arguments with non static names anp.net.mvc-5 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, html-helper

I need to create some groups of `RadioButton`s in my survey. For them to be in separated groups I create name while going through foreach statement. The all have the same begining of the name. There is my code

```
@foreach (var answer in Model.PossibleAnswers)
{
    <div class="col-xs-2">
    @Html.RadioButtonMatrix(answer.IdAspect.ToString(), answer.IdAspect)
    </div>
}
```

And there is my method of custom `Html Helper`

```
public static HtmlString RadioButtonMatrix(this HtmlHelper helper, 
                                           string target, 
                                           int value)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SelectedValue.");
    sb.Append(target);

    string radioButton = 
      String.Format("<input name=\"" + sb + "\" type=\"radio\" value=\"{0}\"/>", value);

    return new HtmlString(radioButton);
}
```

So, is it possible to create a non static name of parametrs in method of controller? 
I found such attribute but suppose that's not that I need

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetAnswersMatrix([Bind(Prefix="SelectedValue")]List<String> selectedValues)
{
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your overall end goal and reasoning is a tad unclear, but if I were you I would likely wrap the `RadioButton` collection in a new class object called `RadioButtonGroup`, you can then give it a name property and it will make your data structure much easier to manager and iterate. Especially if the `Group` is actually just wrapping one question and possible answers, a class object would make this MUCH cleaner and easier to code for.

Comment: I also see little point in `[Bind(Prefix="SelectedValue")]` you only need to bind if you have an object that has properties you want the model binder to purposely ignore. Since you only have 1 object, you will always want to bind to it.

Comment: @Wobbles I alredy have such 'group' - `CertainAnswer`. It is a model for the first demonstrated view. It has `IdAspect` and `List<PossibleAnswerVM>`. But how does it helps me to create different groups of `RadioButtons` and send `selectedValues` as a collection to controller?

Comment: @VitalyIsaenko You need a class for `Group` that contains those properties, the `Group` will then contain the property that groups the answer radios. Will post an example in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose the following data structure to help you out a bit more:

```
class QuizModel
{
    public string HowMuchDoYouLikeCSharp {get;set;}
    public string HowMuchDoYouLikeCPlusPlus {get;set;}
}

public class QuizQuestion
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string QuestionModelProp {get;set;} //This must match a prop name in the QuizModel
    public List<string> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }

    public string generateHTML()
    {
        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
        ret.Append("<div>"+Question+"</div>");
        foreach (string answer in PossibleAnswers)
        {
            ret.Append(String.Format(@"<input name='{0}' type='radio' value='{1}'/>{1}<br/>", QuestionModelProp, answer));
        }

        return ret.ToString();
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitAction(QuizModel quizData)
{      
    string HowMuchDoYouLikeCSharp = quizData.HowMuchDoYouLikeCSharp;
    string HowMuchDoYouLikeCPlusPlus = quizData.HowMuchDoYouLikeCPlusPlus;
}
```

You will have to modify a bit to suit your needs, but this should give you a good stepping off point, even included a rudimentary answer randomizer. To keep it form safe it may be best to treat the form values of answers and questions as hashes or guids rather than the literal strings, but that's an issue for a different question.

Specifically note that since the question and the answers are in the same class, it is easy to create the radio group based on the question on the answer iteration.

**EDIT:** Modified the code to be closer to your needs, also included a model as an example.

Comment: Thank you for the advice but I still don't understand how do you get rhe properly answers (selected `RadioButton`s) in your controller? Could you show it? I have a problem because names of `RadioButtons` are not the same as I see.

Comment: The data string you get in post should be `?Question1=Answer1&Question2=Answer2` With "QuestionN" and "AnswerN" being the actual string Q's and A's. So you just have to make sure your model contains these properties: `var answerOne = Request["Question1"];`

Comment: If you are not using a strongly typed or defined model and want it to be more flexible, you may need to venture outside MVC norms and collect your data into a dictionary iterating the `Request` prop on the `HttpPost` handler.

Comment: I use strongly typed view. What means the last `var answerOne = Request["Question1"]`? Should I give the value right in model? What does it mean? Is it good way to use query string for suchlike things?

Comment: If you are strongly typed it will be more like `public ActionResult SubmitAction(SomeModel model) { var Answer1 = model.Question1; }` You will also have to define a class that is your model, this also means using something other than the question string as the name for the Q's.

Comment: @VitalyIsaenko see the above edited code. Pay particular attention to `QuestionModelProp` that will contain the name of the prop in the model that the question will be formatted into. Also note that the radio name is now the `QuestionModelProp`. That's how the selected value gets mapped into that prop.